# Creating a triangle of numbers from user-input 

Tags: python

I am trying to create a triangle of numbers using Python from user input. I have written a code but not sure how to do one thing in python. I would like to change the print("Next row") to the respective row accordingly. How do i do that?

Code:

```
numstr= raw_input("please enter the height:")
rows = int( )
def triangle(rows):
    for rownum in range (rows)
        PrintingList = list()
        print("Next row")
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = raw_input("Please enter the next number:")
            PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
            print()
```

Is there any mistakes in my code? or is there any suggestions for improvements? please do tell me.. thanks...

Comment: Show the output of what you have, and explain what is wrong with it, preferably with an example of the desired output.

Comment: Your code has a few syntax problems

Comment: @luke14free can u explain what they are... it will be really useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what is desired behaviour for your program, but here is my guess:

```
numstr= raw_input("please enter the height:")

rows = int(numstr) # --> convert user input to an integer
def triangle(rows):
    PrintingList = list()
    for rownum in range (1, rows + 1): # use colon after control structure to denote the beginning of block of code        
        PrintingList.append([]) # append a row
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = raw_input("Please enter the next number:")
            PrintingList[rownum - 1].append(int(newValue))
            print() 

    for item in PrintingList:
      print item
triangle(rows)
```

And here is the output:

```
please enter the height:3
Please enter the next number:1
()
Please enter the next number:2
()
Please enter the next number:3
()
Please enter the next number:4
()
Please enter the next number:5
()
Please enter the next number:4
()
[1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your code to this one:

```
numstr= raw_input("please enter the height:")
rows = int(numstr )
def triangle(rows):
  for rownum in range (rows):
      PrintingList = list()
      print "row #%d" % rownum
      for iteration in range (rownum):
          newValue = raw_input("Please enter the number for row #%d:" % rownum)
          PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
          print()
```

By using the `print "%d" % myint` you can print an integer.

Comment: This won't work in python3, which I *assume* OP is using (because he is invoking `print` as a function).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, change `print("Next row")` to `print("Row no. %i" % rownum)`.

Read the documentation for strings, which explains how `%` format codes work.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    out=''
    for j in range(i+1):
        out+=str(n)
    print(out)
```

This will print the following:

```
>2

2
22

>5

5
55
555
5555
55555
```

Is this what you were looking for?